# Complicated string manipulation in pandas without regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, jupyter-notebook

I just looped over a pandas column to it from out[156] to out[157] in the image attached below.

[image]

Now I have another column that is very complicated, is it possible to achieve the same thing without using regex (I am completely unfamiliar with regex)? I basically want the figures in float format (eg. 9ft 2in to the equivalent in inches) but there are so many different ways it was entered.
[image]

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please add some input and the expected output in a manner that can be copied into a text editor (not images)

Comment: You should probably check out the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) functions.